# SQL query to calculate hours spent from the the other day and ending up on the next day

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

TableName: TimeLog

```
TimeLogID | EmployeeID | TimeLog
------------------------------------------
1         | 1          | 1/1/2013 11:00 PM
2         | 1          | 1/2/2013 07:00 AM
3         | 1          | 1/2/2013 11:00 PM
4         | 1          | 1/3/2013 07:00 AM
```

TableName: Schedule

```
ScheduleID | EmployeeID | TimeIN   | TimeOUT
----------------------------------------------
1          | 1          | 11:00 PM |  07:00 AM
```

My problem here is how could I make a query to calculate the hours spent by an employee given that he or she started working at 11 PM then end up at 7 AM. Hope someone could help me with this problem. Thanks.

Basically, I need the hours worked in every working day.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? You seem to be hedging your bets...

Comment: and where is the primary key?

Comment: I think either is fine, because all I need is an sql query that may be able to calculate those hours that started from the past day and end up with a new day.

Comment: How do you identify what is a start and what is a finish? is it just that the first row will be a start and the second a finish?

Comment: A person logged in at 11 PM and logged out on 7 AM.

Comment: Doy you need the sum of all workdays i a timeframe or just one single entry?

Comment: I need the hours worked in every working day, depending on the employee schedule. And in this case, it is 11 PM to 7 AM.

Comment: We know that you know that. But how does MySQL know that?

Comment: How do you know they didn't work from `1/2/2013 07:00` until `1/2/2013 11:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Oracle query to calc time diff only. I think it should work in any SQL if you replace dual with your table. There are LAG/LEAD functions to compare prev/next row values but I do not know if those are available in your version of SQL. I hope this is useful to you:

```
SELECT trunc(mydate / 3600) hr
 , trunc(mod(mydate, 3600) / 60) mnt
 , trunc(mod(mydate, 3600) / 60 /60) sec
  FROM 
  (
   SELECT (to_date('01/02/2013 23:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy  hh24:mi:ss') -
           to_date('01/01/2013 07:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy  hh24:mi:ss')) * 86400 mydate
    FROM dual
  )
 /
```

Comment: Is it correct @bendataclear? The MySQL function to convert to a date is [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function%5Fstr-to-date) and the SQL Server is [CAST() or CONVERT()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). TO_DATE() is Oracle only, as Art mentioned (so fair enough), but the OP hasn't tagged the question Oracle so the answer is technically "wrong".

Comment: @Ben, Just because something isn't perfect doesn't mean it's not helpful, there aren't just black and white answers here. Also if you feel the need for the down vote you should highlight what you feel is incorrect so the poster can correct it or others are not misled.

Comment: @bendataclear; that assumes that I was the one who downvoted. There are 1m people on this site, so that's a fairly broad assumption. I was pointing out that the answer was technically incorrect, which is reason enough for a downvote from any one of them. I'd also like to address your first point _"there aren't just black and white answers here"_. This is a Q&A _programming_ website there is normally a correct answer (there may of course be more than 1); it's the nature of the beast. Code is either correct or incorrect.

Comment: @Ben Code is not simply correct or incorrect, it can be functional but very inefficient, in this case the code is 'correct' as it works within oracle, and the RDBMS was never confirmed. Also, it's since been accepted as most helpful by the poster. On top I'd like to add that I didn't say the answer was correct, I said I was correcting a down-vote without explanation, sorry if you mis-understood this.

Comment: @bendataclear; we're going to have to agree to disagree. The RDBMS is stated in the question (both of them, but definitively not Oracle) and has been since the beginning. "Correcting" an downvote seems a bit wrong somehow; what right have you to take away someone else's right to do so? You should be upvoting for whatever reasons you wish, of course, but upvoting because it's what you would have answered or because you like the way the poster has solved a problem etc would be more normal.

Comment: @ben, yes I can agree to that ;) I have up-voted the answer because it is the most helpful (in mine and the posters opinion), 'correcting the down-vote' comment is to encourage down-voters to add constructive criticism, something I feel important on SO.

Comment: @All. If there is no such thing as TO_DATE() function in other versions of SQL then it can always be replaced with smth that is used instead, and query will work fine and bring correct results, which is 40 hours difference between those dates, not 20... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query

```
select
  e.TimeLogID,
  e.EmployeeID,
  ifnull(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,e.TimeLog,la.TimeLog),0) as timediff
from emp_time as e
left join (
        select 
            * 
        from emp_time
    ) as la on la.TimeLogID = (
                    select  
                        min(TimeLogID ) 
                    from emp_time 
                    where TimeLogID  > e.TimeLogID  
                    limit 1
                );
```

Output

```
TimeLogID EmployeeID timediff 
1           1           20 
2           1           4 
3           1           20 
4           1           0
```

Comment: And why was it that there is a time difference of 20? Was it computed from 11 PM to 7 AM? Because I think 20 is just exceeding...I think it will just be having a calculated result of 8 hours from 11 PM to 7 AM.