# Copy a row once for each spanned hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to copy each row as many times as how many hours there are between `StartTime` and `EndTime`.

Example data:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/587a4/1)**

```
TimeKey HourKey SensorKey   IdleTimeMinute  StartTime   EndTime
20121017    8   45  110 2012.10.17 08:31    2012.10.17 10:21
20121017    10  45  25  2012.10.17 10:26    2012.10.17 10:51
20121017    12  45  5   2012.10.17 12:21    2012.10.17 12:26
20121017    12  45  60  2012.10.17 12:41    2012.10.17 13:41
20121017    13  45  55  2012.10.17 13:51    2012.10.17 14:46
20121017    15  45  5   2012.10.17 15:11    2012.10.17 15:16
20121017    15  45  35  2012.10.17 15:46    2012.10.17 16:21
20121017    18  45  5   2012.10.17 18:51    2012.10.17 18:56
```

**Explanation**

For example, the first row spans the hours 8, 9, and 10. In each of the three output rows, `IdleTimeMinute` needs to be the minutes duration within that hour.

Expected Result:

```
TimeKey HourKey SensorKey   IdleTimeMinute  StartTime   EndTime
20121017    8   45  29  2012.10.17 08:31    2012.10.17 10:21
20121017    9   45  60  2012.10.17 08:31    2012.10.17 10:21
20121017    10  45  21  2012.10.17 08:31    2012.10.17 10:21
20121017    10  45  25  2012.10.17 10:26    2012.10.17 10:51
20121017    12  45  5   2012.10.17 12:21    2012.10.17 12:26
20121017    12  45  19  2012.10.17 12:41    2012.10.17 13:41
20121017    13  45  41  2012.10.17 12:41    2012.10.17 13:41
20121017    13  45  9   2012.10.17 13:51    2012.10.17 14:46
20121017    14  45  46  2012.10.17 13:51    2012.10.17 14:46
20121017    15  45  5   2012.10.17 15:11    2012.10.17 15:16
20121017    15  45  14  2012.10.17 15:46    2012.10.17 16:21
20121017    16  45  21  2012.10.17 15:46    2012.10.17 16:21
20121017    18  45  5   2012.10.17 18:51    2012.10.17 18:56
```

**Smaller Example**

Smaller example from first two lines:

```
TimeKey HourKey SensorKey   IdleTimeMinute  StartTime   EndTime
20121017    8   45  110 2012.10.17 08:31    2012.10.17 10:21
20121017    10  45  25  2012.10.17 10:26    2012.10.17 10:51
```

For first line we have time `8:31 - 10:21` so In 8 Hour 29 Minutes, In 9 Hour 60 Minutes, In 10 Hour 21 Minute.

Expected small result:

```
TimeKey HourKey SensorKey   IdleTimeMinute  StartTime   EndTime
20121017    8   45  29  2012.10.17 08:31    2012.10.17 10:21
20121017    9   45  60  2012.10.17 08:31    2012.10.17 10:21
20121017    10  45  21  2012.10.17 08:31    2012.10.17 10:21
20121017    10  45  25  2012.10.17 10:26    2012.10.17 10:51
```

Comment: Where is the second row `2012.10.17 10:26    2012.10.17 10:51`?

Comment: In the first part of your statement you say you need to copy a table multiple times but then in the next part it's a row. Which one is it?  The problem you've laid out is very hard to follow too.

Comment: Second row is grouped with first In 10 Hour. First row got in 10 hour 21 minute, second row got 25. So if we group by hour we get 46 minutes in 10 Hour.

Comment: If IdleTimeMinute is the "duration minutes in that hour", how can it be over 60?  (see row #1).

Comment: You're edits definitely help clear things up.  I think I see what you are needing now.

Comment: How do you determine the value of IdleTimeMinute for the new row and existing rows?  So for your new example, the two rows had values of 110 and 25 but the three new rows now have 29, 60, and 46.  I see that they add up correctly but not sure how you are coming up with the new results.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: `MS SQL SERVER` - Database I edites Question

Comment: For HourKey 10, why does the StartTime change for that one?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how this HourKey works? (especially for the new values)

Comment: My Data was a little wrong now I editet Question.

Comment: To calc time difference between two dates - Oracle example that can be easily converted to SQL Server - replace to_date() with smth similar in SQL SERVER and use any table instead of dual: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562277/sql-query-to-calculate-hours-spent-from-the-the-other-day-and-ending-up-on-the-n/14564293#14564293
Nice SQL SERVER blog - Create Dual: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/20/sql-server-select-from-dual-dual-equivalent/

Comment: What happens if you go past midnight? Will the new rows past midnight need to show a `TimeKey` with the date of the next day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. This will handle even cases where the span of time passes midnight or goes over many days. It should perform very well.

See [the SqlFiddle for it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d828a/7).

```
DECLARE @MaxHour int = IsNull((SELECT Max(DateDiff(hour, StartTime, EndTime)) + 1 FROM dbo.Table1), 0);

WITH L0 AS (SELECT 1 N UNION ALL SELECT 1),
L1 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM L0, L0 B),
L2 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM L1, L1 B),
L3 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM L2, L2 B),
L4 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM L3, L3 B),
L5 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM L4, L4 B),
Nums AS (SELECT Num = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM L5)
SELECT
   TimeKey = Convert(int, Convert(char(8), S.HourStartTime, 112)),
   HourKey = DatePart(hour, S.HourStartTime),
   T.SensorKey,
   IdleTimeMinute = DateDiff(minute, S.HourStartTime, E.HourEndTime),
   T.StartTime,
   T.EndTime,
   S.HourStartTime,
   E.HourEndTime
FROM
   dbo.Table1 T
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT AnchorHour = DateAdd(hour, DateDiff(hour, 0, T.StartTime) + N.Num - 1, 0)
      FROM Nums N
      WHERE
         DateDiff(hour, T.StartTime, T.EndTime) + 1 >= N.Num
         AND N.Num <= @MaxHour
   ) D
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT HourStartTime = Max(StartTime)
      FROM (VALUES (D.AnchorHour), (T.StartTime)) S (StartTime)
   ) S
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT HourEndTime = Min(EndTime)
      FROM (VALUES (DateAdd(hour, 1, D.AnchorHour)), (T.EndTime)) E (EndTime)
   ) E
ORDER BY
   TimeKey,
   StartTime,
   HourKey;
```

I included the new timespan for the selected hour. If you want that timespan to end at `:59` instead of `:00` of the next hour, then in the third `CROSS APPLY` change `DateAdd(hour, 1, D.AnchorHour)` to `DateAdd(minute, 59, D.AnchorHour)` and add `+ 1` to the end of `DateDiff(minute, S.HourStartTime, E.HourEndTime)` in the `SELECT` clause.

In my opinion:

- Using a CTE to incrementally add one's way up to the max difference is not optimal. The CTE I use bails out close to as soon as the max Num is reached, and can go up to 4294967296.
- Solutions that don't calculate the new TimeKey are fragile due to depending on an unstated assumption that midnight cannot be crossed.
- Solutions that depend on you changing your table to have a monotonically-increasing ID with no gaps are unlikely to fit your real-world data.

Note: the reason I declare the @MaxHour variable is that the on-the-fly numbers table CTE I'm using wants a constant. Well, that's not exactly accurate, but the long and short of it is that without a constant it can choose an execution plan that doesn't limit the rows in the place needed to get a speedy query. I chose `DateDiff` to compute this, but in fact I see now that this would probably be faster, and definitely would be faster if you have an index on IdleTimeMinute:

```
DECLARE @MaxHour int = IsNull((SELECT (Max(IdleTimeMinute) + 118) / 60 FROM dbo.Table1), 0);
```

Since the smallest time range that can span two different hours is 2 minutes (say 11:59 to 12:00) then we have to add 118 minutes to be sure to get at least 2 hours out of it.

Comment: Very good,  that really works if time passes midnight or goes over many days http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d47a8/2 .
Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a mess but based on your SQL fiddle you could do

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (RowNumber INT Identity(1,1),[TimeKey] int, [HourKey] int, 

[SensorKey] int, [IdleTimeMinute] int, [StartTime] datetime, [EndTime] datetime)

INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT *
FROM Table1

DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME, @EndTime DATETIME
DECLARE @Total INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp)
DECLARE @x INT = 1
DECLARE @TotalHours INT = 0
WHILE @i <= @Total + 1
BEGIN

SET @StartTime = (SELECT StartTime FROM #temp WHERE RowNumber = @i)
SET @EndTime = (SELECT EndTime FROM #temp WHERE RowNumber = @i)               
SET @x = 1
SET @TotalHours = (SELECT DATEDIFF(Hour,@StartTime,@EndTime))

WHILE @x <= @TotalHours
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT * FROM #Temp WHERE RowNumber = @i
SET @x = @x + 1
END
SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT * FROM Table2
```

which is under the assumption you've got a second table with this layout

```
CREATE TABLE Table2
    (RowNumber INT, [TimeKey] int, [HourKey] int, [SensorKey] int, [IdleTimeMinute] int, [StartTime] datetime, [EndTime] datetime)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. A limitation for generating sequence. If your `IdleTimeMinute` is unexpected great you must use `OPTION (MAXRECURSION n)` from CTE. Query can run from SQL Server 2005+. For older version you must use your own sequence generation mechanism.

```
;WITH Times
AS
(
  SELECT 1 Id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Id + 1 
  FROM Times
  WHERE Id < 100
)
SELECT
  R.* ,
  CASE WHEN (IDLETIMEMINUTE - 60 * (T.Id - 1)) / 60 > 0 
      THEN 60
      ELSE (IDLETIMEMINUTE % 60)
   END IDLETIMEMINUTE_New
FROM Table1 R
  JOIN Times T
     ON T.Id <= CEILING(R.[IdleTimeMinute]/60.0)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/587a4/39)**

Answer (score 0):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/587a4/84)

```
WITH    q(n) AS
        (
        SELECT  0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  n + 1
        FROM    q
        WHERE   n <23
        )
select TimeKey,
       q.n as HourKey,
       SensorKey,
       (select min(V) from 
         (select ETime-q.n*60 as V
          union all
          select ((q.n+1)*60)-sTime as V
          union all 
          select 60 as V          
         )  x
       ) as IdleTimeMinute,
       StartTime,
       EndTime
from q 
join 
(
select *,
DATEPART(HOUR, starttime)*60
   +DATEPART(MINUTE, starttime) sTime,
DATEPART(HOUR, Endtime)*60
   +DATEPART(MINUTE, Endtime) eTime
from 
table1 
) t1
on q.n*60 between (t1.sTime/60)*60 and t1.eTime
order by TimeKEy,SensorKey,HourKey,StartTime
```